# computing sum nested loop unbalanced longitudinal data in R

Tags: r

I need to compute a sum over each j for each i in a nested loop as follows and then output the sum for each i as a list.  The problem is that the code gets very slow for large number of observations. Is there any way to avoid loop so that the code can run faster ? Thanks.

```
#### generate data
 set.seed(234)

 N=3
 v<-sample(2:6,N,replace=TRUE)
 id<-c(rep(1:N,v))
 n<-length(id)
 x<-as.matrix(cbind(rnorm(n,0,1),rnorm(n,0,1),rnorm(n,0,1)))
 x1<-cbind(id,x)
 e<-runif(3)

 > v
 [1] 5 5 2
 id
  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3
> x
            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
 [1,]  0.7590390 -0.8716028 -0.30554099
 [2,]  0.3713058  1.1876234  0.86956546
 [3,]  0.5758514 -0.6672287 -1.06121591
 [4,] -0.5703207  0.5383396 -0.09635967
 [5,]  0.1198567  0.4905632  0.47460932
 [6,]  0.2095484 -1.0216529 -0.02671707
 [7,] -0.1481357 -0.3726091  1.10167492
 [8,]  0.6433900  1.3251178 -0.26842418
 [9,]  1.1348350 -0.7313432  0.01035965
[10,]  0.1995994  0.7625386  0.25897152
[11,]  0.2987197  0.3275333 -0.39459737
[12,] -0.3191671 -1.1440187 -0.48873668

> e
[1] 0.3800745 0.5497359 0.3893235


 ### compute sum

  sumterm_<-list()
  count=1
 for (i in 1:N){
   idd=x1[,1]==i
   xi=x[idd,]
  sumterm=matrix(rep(0,N*N),nrow=3,ncol=3)
  for (j in 1:v[i]){
    xij=xi[j,]
     sumterm=sumterm+as.matrix(xij-e)%*%(xij-e)
     count=count+1
  }
   sumterm_[[i]]<-sumterm
  }

sumterm_
[[1]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]  1.1529838 -0.7562553 -0.1121242
[2,] -0.7562553  3.9117383  3.0597216
[3,] -0.1121242  3.0597216  3.0606953

[[2]]
             [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
 [1,]  0.97965490 -0.04598867 -0.74102232
 [2,] -0.04598867  5.60764839 -0.05553464
 [3,] -0.74102232 -0.05553464  1.27377151

[[3]]
          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.4955573 1.202421 0.6777518
[2,] 1.2024208 2.918179 1.6614076
[3,] 0.6777518 1.661408 1.3855215
```

Comment: You are growing your object. Rookie 101 mistake in R Preallocate everything and fill in the result. . See [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/) for more tips on how to avoid bad practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some steps that could be taken to improve the code:

- Allocate all the space for your output object in one go

  `sumterm_ <- lapply(1:N,function(x){matrix(0,3,3)})`
- calculate x-e once, rather than repeating the same caluculations

  `xbar <- x-rep(e, each=n)`
- use `drop=FALSE` to avoid converting matrix to vector and back again

  `xbar[i,] %*% xbar[i,,drop=FALSE]`
- write directly to the output object

  `sumterm_[[id[i]]] <- sumterm_[[id[i]]] + xbar[i,] %*% xbar[i,,drop=FALSE]`

So the complete code looks like:

```
  #List of zero matrices
  sumterm_ <- lapply(1:N,function(x){matrix(0,3,3)})

  #Calculate x-e
  xbar <- x-rep(e, each=n)

  #sum by id 
  for (i in 1:n){
    sumterm_[[id[i]]] <- sumterm_[[id[i]]] + xbar[i,] %*% xbar[i,,drop=FALSE]
  }
```

An alternative approach might be to rewrite using the apply functions (although these implement loops within, rather than eliminating them).

```
#calculate cross product for each row
cps <- apply(x-rep(e, each=n), 1, tcrossprod)

#aggregate columns by id variable, and convert to matrix
sumterm2_ <- tapply(seq_along(id), id, 
                    function(i){matrix(rowSums(cps[, i, drop=FALSE]), 3, 3)})
```

Comparing speed between different approaches depends on the direction that the problem scales in - that's why there's no time comparison between methods.